# How to convert int to char type and use it to stop loop?

Tags: c

I am new in C programming. I wrote a programme with "for" loop which will take two int type inputs K and M and print out the calculation (of hash function in division method). And if I enter q or Q as the input of K or M then it will exit. How will i do that? anyone help me.

```
int main(){

int K;
int M;

for(;;)
{
    printf("Enter the value of K: \n");
    scanf("%d",&K);

    printf("Enter the value of M: \n");
    scanf("%d",&M);

    printf("The Hash address of %d and %d is %d",K,M,K%M);
}
return system("pause");}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks the return of `scanf()` to see if the scan was successful. If not, the buffer is cleared and checked for a 'q' that indicates that the program should exit.
`getint()` accepts a prompt message and a pointer to a flag. Setting the flag to -1 tells the caller to exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int getint ( char *prompt, int *result);

int main ( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int K, M;
    int ok = 0;

    do {
        K = getint ( "\nEnter the value of K ( or q to quit)\n", &ok);
        if ( ok == -1) {
            break;
        }
        M = getint ( "\nEnter the value of M ( or q to quit)\n", &ok);
        if ( ok == -1) {
            break;
        }
        printf("\nThe Hash address of %d and %d is %d\n", K, M, K % M);
    } while ( ok != -1);

    return 0;
}

//the function can return only one value.
//int *result allows setting a flag:
//  0 the function is looping
//  1 the function is returning a valid int
// -1 the function returns and the program should exit
// the caller can see the flag of 1 or -1
int getint ( char *prompt, int *result)
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;

    *result = 0;

    do {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        if ( scanf("%d",&n) != 1) {// scan one int
            while ( ( i = getchar ( )) != '\n' && i != 'q') {
                //clear buffer on scanf failure
                //stop on newline
                //quit if a q is found
            }
            if ( i != 'q') {
                printf ( "problem with input, try again\n");
            }
            else {//found q. return and exit
                *result = -1;
                n = 0;
            }
        }
        else {//scanf success
            *result = 1;//return a valid int
        }
    } while ( *result == 0);

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Although some minor weakness to `int getint()`, rolling a separate function to handle the similar inputs of a number or 'q' for `K, M` is a good approach. + 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){

char str[255];
int K;
int M;

for(;;)
{
    printf("Enter the value of K: \n");
    scanf("%s", &str);
    if (str[0] == 'q' || str[0] == 'Q') break;
    sscanf(str, "%d",&K);

    printf("Enter the value of M: \n");
    scanf("%s", &str);
    if (str[0] == 'q' || str[0] == 'Q') break;
    sscanf(str, "%d",&M);

    printf("The Hash address of %d and %d is %d",K,M,K%M);
}
return system("pause");}
```

Comment: You should really check the return values of both `scanf()` and `sscanf()` to know whether the operations succeeded or not.  The code just assumes it does.  For example, entering `Z Z` will generate problems.

Comment: Sure. I wrote minimal working code, leaving the rest to the author.

Comment: On the whole, you're more likely to get up-votes (from people like me, for example) if the code you show covers most of the bases.  It doesn't necessarily have to cover everything that production-ready code has to deal with, but it should cover basic good practices such as testing that input operations succeed.  You're at liberty to ignore this advice; I'm at liberty not to up-vote, too.